# Crackling sound coming through earphone

Tags: windows, bluetooth

While pairing Oppo Enco earbuds with my laptop why the sounds keeps breaking? Like everyone 2 seconds the sound came and then it breaks and then the sound comes and keeps repeating. It is working fine in others systems. Every Bluetooth earphone starts producing crackling sound while i paired it to my laptop.

I have already tried re-installing the Bluetooth drivers.